# Oracle reg_replace Replace matched and keep alpha characters only

Tags: oracle, plsql, preg-replace

I am stuck and not finding solution in one or two lines.

Actually I have one string e.g. "Romeo (-& -must 123) die (but123) not now" I want the output like "Romeo (must) die (but) not now"

I want to use regreplace in oracle to achieve the same in one or two lines. I know it can achieve by using multi line coding but need in efficient way.

I tried this but not working

```
select
  (REGEXP_REPLACE('Romeo (-& -must 123) die (but123) not now', '\((.*?)\)', '[^A-Z'']')) "REGEXP_REPLACE"
  FROM dual;
```

It will be great if someone can help me.

Comment: Are you only concerned with replacing non-alphabetical characters within parenthesis?

Comment: Yes eplacing non-alphabetical characters within parenthesis

Comment: For curiosity's sake, what about nested parenthesis? Should we assume you will not encounter these? Also, I assume you will not have "incomplete" parenthetical expressions (start or end of parenthesis, yet not paired), right?

Comment: this gets you pretty close but has spaces still on the '( must )'. select
  REGEXP_REPLACE('Romeo (-& -must 123) die (but123) not now', '[^a-zA-Z() ]', '')
FROM dual;

Comment: Number of code lines has no relation to effiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample size is minimal but the following regular expression resolves your issue. It will likely broke with some other inputs but please don't expect us to guess your patterns.

The regexp explained:

1. `\(` match opening paranthesis
2. `.*?` match any character zero or more times non-greedily
3. `(` start subexpression. This is later backreferenced with `\1` in replace string.
4. `[[:alpha:]]+` match one or more alphabetic characters
5. `)` end subexpression
6. `.*?` match any character zero or more times non-greedily
7. `\)` match closing paranthesis

**Example**

```
with
t(orig) as (
  select 'Romeo (-& -must 123) die (but123) not now' from dual
)
select
 orig
,regexp_replace(orig, '\(.*?([[:alpha:]]+).*?\)', '(\1)') as replaced
from t
;
```

**Output**

```
ORIG                                      REPLACED
----------------------------------------- ------------------------------
Romeo (-& -must 123) die (but123) not now Romeo (must) die (but) not now
```